# How to retrive value of p_name and total_qty from the following array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
string(1) "5" string(5) "shop2" array(7) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { ["p_name"]=> string(9) "Coca Cola" ["total_qty"]=> string(1) "5" } 
    [1]=> array(2) { ["p_name"]=> string(13) "Fried Chicken" ["total_qty"]=> string(1) "8" } 
    [2]=> array(2) { ["p_name"]=> string(10) "Fried Rice" ["total_qty"]=> string(1) "3" } 
    [3]=> array(2) { ["p_name"]=> string(16) "Fried Vermicelli" ["total_qty"]=> string(1) "5" } 
    [4]=> array(2) { ["p_name"]=> string(13) "Friedn Noodle" ["total_qty"]=> string(1) "5" } 
    [5]=> array(2) { ["p_name"]=> string(5) "Sushi" ["total_qty"]=> string(1) "5" } 
    [6]=> array(2) { ["p_name"]=> string(12) "Test Product" ["total_qty"]=> string(1) "2" } }
```

> Blockquote
>   that the above array name is $itemm..i called that $itemm['p_name'] but i cann't.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: i edited my question.

Comment: Is it a matter of doing something like `$array[5]["p_name"]` ? Is that the question or are you looking for something specific in the array?

Comment: `p_name` doesnt seem to be a key of `$itemn`, but a key of arrays that are inside `$itemn`. Something like this (to get the first item for example) should work. `$itemm[0]['p_name'] `

Comment: <?php  foreach ($item as $itemm) : ?>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= $itemm; $i++) {  ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $item['product_data'][$i]['p_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['product_data'][$i]['total_qty'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>


i want to that
i get <?php echo $item['product_data'][0]['p_name'] 

 echo $item['product_data'][1]['p_name'] 
?>
but i cann't get the above code

Comment: let the above result is $item. Ho could I retrive the relevant p_name and total_qty from  that the result

Answer (score 0):

You error in $itemm[p_name]
You can change to $itemm['p_name']

Comment: sorry, i forget single code. i have tested project included single code.

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: @NguyễnAnhĐức I think he wanted to write *quote* instead *code* (He has already tried, it's not related to quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Using your posted input array, this is how you can print the subarray values into table rows:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/421ae44b0dabd8db7fd48508757444e0c621a1f6))

```
$itemm=["5",
        "shop2",
        [
            ["p_name"=>"Coca Cola","total_qty"=>"5"],
            ["p_name"=>"Fried Chicken","total_qty"=>"8"],
            ["p_name"=>"Fried Rice","total_qty"=>"3"],
            ["p_name"=>"Fried Vermicelli","total_qty"=>"5"],
            ["p_name"=>"Friedn Noodle","total_qty"=>"5"],
            ["p_name"=>"Sushi","total_qty"=>"5"],
            ["p_name"=>"Test Product","total_qty"=>"2"]
        ]
    ];
foreach($itemm[2] as $rows){
    echo "<tr><td>{$rows['p_name']}</td><td>{$rows['p_name']}</td></tr>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<tr><td>Coca Cola</td><td>Coca Cola</td></tr>
<tr><td>Fried Chicken</td><td>Fried Chicken</td></tr>
<tr><td>Fried Rice</td><td>Fried Rice</td></tr>
<tr><td>Fried Vermicelli</td><td>Fried Vermicelli</td></tr>
<tr><td>Friedn Noodle</td><td>Friedn Noodle</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sushi</td><td>Sushi</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test Product</td><td>Test Product</td></tr>
```

Comment: @Jurina If this does not reflect the structure of your actual input array, please post a truer sample array in your question.